# Digital Ocean Let's Encrypt domain list is empty even though I have a domain setup

Tags: ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I have connected a domain from one of the major domain registrars to digital ocean. I can access the site through the domain through it's url but I want to protect it with ssl. I have decided to create a load balancer, however, when I get to the point when I need to select a domain to use to create the ssl certificate, there are no domains in the list. When I try to create a new one through there, it tells me that it `Must be a valid registered domain name`.

Regardless of that, it never propagated the domain that I know exists when I tried to search for it using Let's Encrypt.

My domain has an A and a AAAA record.

Why wouldn't my domain show up in the list?